# MVC4 what is the simplest way of allowing a user to download a file (pdf)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I need to serve a file for my users, this file could be a pdf or an xls file.

i cant seem to find a simple way of doing this.

this is what i have come pu with:

```
public FileResult DownloadPDF()
     {


         return view("/download/pdf1");
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the quickest way would be to do something like this:

```
  public ActionResult DownloadPdf()
  {
    return File("~/Download/pdf1.pdf", "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("NameOfFile.pdf"));
  }
```

Comment: how can I make the name of the downloaded file "TESTPDF1"?

Comment: like this: return File("~/Download/pdf1.pdf", "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("TESTPDF1.pdf"));

Answer (score 0):

Best and fastest way that i have found:

```
public void DownloadReport(string path)
        {
            // Clear the content of the response
            Response.ClearContent();
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(path);

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFile.Name) + DateTime.Now + newFile.Extension;

            // LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            // Add the file size into the response header
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", newFile.Length.ToString());

            // Set the ContentType
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
            Response.TransmitFile(newFile.FullName);

            // End the response
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            //send statistics to the class        

        }
```

Pass the path of your file to this method & change content type as per your file type.